# Splitting field and adding decimal point to create numeric value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a field in SQL Server 2014 that I am working with that looks like this:

```
**RawField**
20060202
20060323
```

I want to add a split the field and add a decimal point and create a numerical field. This is what I would like to see:

```
**RawField**
200602.02
200603.23
```

So I need to split the field, add the decimal point, and convert to a numerical value. I tried some code but was getting an error. Please see my code below:

```
  select top 1000 cast(SUBSTRING(cast(RawField as varchar(6)),1,6) + cast('.' as varchar(1)) + SUBSTRING(cast(RawField as varchar(2)),6,2) as int)
  from Table
```

I get an error of:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '200602.' to data type int.
```

Is this a good approach?

Comment: What's the original type of the column, sans all the casting? (Also, is this possibly a `DATE` in poor disguise, instead of anything numeric?)

Comment: Why are you trying to cast `200602.02` as an INT?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Originally it's a varchar(50). It was a file dump from a text file

Comment: What version of SQL Server (2012+ has `PARSE`, which could be used here together with `STUFF`), and what kind of "numerical field" are you looking for? `DECIMAL(8, 2)` would be the obvious choice, but that contradicts casting to `INT`. If you just want to put a period in the value, but keep it as a string, that would be a simple application of `STUFF`, but the result wouldn't really be "numerical" as far as the database is concerned.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you! I think you hit it perfectly. I would prefer DECIMAL(8,2). I was having issues with it so I just tried INT just to try out the code. I just wrote CAST(STUFF(RawField, 7, 0, '.') AS DECIMAL(8,2)) and got my answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
select top 1000 cast(SUBSTRING(cast(RawField as varchar(6)),1,6) + cast('.' as varchar(1)) + SUBSTRING(cast(RawField as varchar(2)),6,2) as numeric(8,2))
  from Table
```

You are trying to cast string with decimal number to int.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: Never do with `SUBSTRING` what `STUFF` can achieve, I say. :-P `STUFF(RawField, 7, 0, '.')`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you so much! That works and is so much quicker!!

Answer (score 2):

you want to convert the string to numeric with 2 decimal places ?

```
select convert(decimal(10,2), RawField) / 100.0
```

I guest your RawField contains other alphanumeric after that and you only posted the first 8 characters ?

this should work. Just take the first 8 characters and convert. Simple and direct

```
select convert(decimal(10,2), left(RawField, 8)) / 100.0
```

Comment: Squirrel, thank you for responding, but i get an error of "Error converting data type varchar to numeric." I think I got my answer from @nitzien. When I run that bit of code it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use float/numeric/decimal when casting

```
select cast(SUBSTRING(RawField ,1,6) + cast('.' as varchar(1)) + SUBSTRING(RawField ,7,2) as numeric(16,2))
```

Comment: Why float? That is not really what they want to do. You should use numeric instead because float is an approximate datatype.

Comment: But don't suggest float, it is the wrong datatype here.